# Event handling bug with SDL

Tags: c++, events, sdl

I am making a snake game using SDL and C++, and I found a bug involving events.

In this game, there are two important functions for now : the play function (the "main" function of the game) and the pause function. When the P key is pressed, the play function calls and executes the pause function. In it, you have two possibilities: either continue or quit the game.

Now, here is the problem. When I try to click "Continue game", the game flashes for a split second and comes back to the pause menu. When I keep the mouse button down, I realize the game itself is frozen until an event of any kind happens. If it does, it just comes back to where it was.

After some tests, I also noticed that the bug was due to the SDL_PollEvent function. So I changed this function in the play function to SDL_WaitEvent, which put the game back when I asked him to. However, another problem is created: since, in my play function, there is a timer that uses SDL_GetTicks, the game needs a trigger event to be fluid. For example, when I constantly move the cursor in any direction, the game can run. When I stop, it freezes.

Is there a way to fix this bug?

Here is the event handler in the play function:

```
SDL_PollEvent(&event); // Handle events
switch(event.type)
{
    case SDL_QUIT:
        quit = true;
        break;
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        switch(event.key.keysym.sym) // Change direction at certain key press
        {
            case SDLK_s:
                currentDirection = SNAKE_DOWN;
                break;
            case SDLK_w:
                currentDirection = SNAKE_UP;
                break;
            case SDLK_a:
                currentDirection = SNAKE_LEFT;
                break;
            case SDLK_d:
                currentDirection = SNAKE_RIGHT;
                break;
            case SDLK_ESCAPE: // Quit if escape key pressed
                quit = true;
                break;
            case SDLK_p:
                if (pause(screen) == false)
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                break;
            default: ; // Code to block the compiler's -Wall flag (does not do anything to the program itself)
        }
        break;
}
```

And here is the complete pause function:

```
bool pause(SDL_Surface *screen)
{
    SDL_Surface *pauseMessage, *continueButton, *quitButton;
    SDL_Rect posPauseMessage, posContinueButton, posQuitButton;
    TTF_Font *fipps;
    SDL_Color color = {255, 255, 255};
    SDL_Event event;
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    bool quit = false, returnFalse = false;

    fipps = TTF_OpenFont("fipps.ttf", 50);
    pauseMessage = TTF_RenderText_Blended(fipps, "PAUSED", color);
    continueButton = TTF_RenderText_Blended(fipps, "Continue Game", color);
    quitButton = TTF_RenderText_Blended(fipps, "Exit to menu", color);

    posPauseMessage.x = (screen->w - pauseMessage->w) / 2;
    posPauseMessage.y = 200;

    posContinueButton.x = (screen->w - continueButton->w) / 2;
    posContinueButton.y = posPauseMessage.y + 200;

    posQuitButton.x = (screen->w - quitButton->w) / 2;
    posQuitButton.y = posContinueButton.y + 100;

    while (!quit)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                returnFalse = true;
                quit = true;
                break;
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                x = event.button.x;
                y = event.button.y;

                if ((x > posContinueButton.x) && (x < posContinueButton.x + continueButton->w) && (y > posContinueButton.y) && (y < posContinueButton.y + continueButton->h))
                    quit = true;
                else if ((x > posQuitButton.x) && (x < posQuitButton.x + quitButton->w) && (y > posQuitButton.y) && (y < posQuitButton.y + quitButton->h))
                    returnFalse = true;
                    quit = true;

                break;
        }

        SDL_FillRect(screen, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 0, 0, 0));
        SDL_BlitSurface(pauseMessage, NULL, screen, &posPauseMessage);
        SDL_BlitSurface(continueButton, NULL, screen, &posContinueButton);
        SDL_BlitSurface(quitButton, NULL, screen, &posQuitButton);
        SDL_Flip(screen);
    }

    TTF_CloseFont(fipps);
    SDL_FreeSurface(pauseMessage);
    SDL_FreeSurface(continueButton);
    SDL_FreeSurface(quitButton);

    if (returnFalse)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: SDL_WaitEvent block your game until an event is launched. You should put your SDL_PollEvent into a loop, else you only get the first event on the stack and only one event per frame.

Comment: ...or fire off a custom event in a [timer callback](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_AddTimer) to trigger a redraw.

Comment: @jordsti Yeah, it's a good idea. I didn't use it at first though, because the way I learned to do event handlers is like shown above. But great idea, I'll try it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jordsti, I found a solution : I need to put the SDL_PollEvent as a condition for a while loop, which contains the switch block.